# Counting matches in vector of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, iterator, std

I have a problem that requires me to count the number of instances within this array that uses either `std::count()` or `std::find()`. I'm aware of how to do this using a standard data (see bottom code) type but not with the `NameContainer` that I'm using.

```
//Type
struct NameContainer{
    char name [32];
}

//An array of containers
NameContainer *_storedNames = new NameContainer[_numberOfNames];

//An example of what I'm trying to do with a string rather than the NameContainer
std::vector<string> v(_storedNames, _storedNames + _numberOfNames);
//returns an numeric value
return std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), nameToSearch))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a functor

```
struct names_equal {
    string comp_to;

    names_equal(string a) : comp_to(a) {}

    bool operator()(NameContainer& p) {
        return p.name == comp_to;
    }
};
```

And count like

```
cout << std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), names_equal(nameToSearch));
```

This way `nameToSearch` doesn't have to be hard coded.

---

**EDIT**

If you can not use `count_if`, and has to be `count` then modify NameContainer and overload == for it.

```
struct NameContainer{
    string name;

    bool operator==(string str) {
        return name == str;
    }
};
```

Then count like this

```
cout << std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), nameToSearch);
```

Comment: I have fixed it. But I don't understand why he can use `count` and not `count_if`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding the explicit nature it's part of an assignment that requires either those two.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `count_if` and you provide a predicate (Unary function that accepts an element in the range as argument, and returns a value convertible to bool)
for example

```
bool myPred(NameContainer n){
  return (strcmp(n.name, "name") == 0); }

std::vector<NameContainer> v(_storedNames, _storedNames + _numberOfNames);

int i=std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), myPred))
```

you can use `strcmp()` to compare character arrays.

if using only `std::count` or `std::find`:

both count and find takes the same type argument to compare as the type of conatainer, in your case `NameContainer`. `std::count` will execute following to compare searched values:

```
if (*first == val)
```

what means you have to overload `operator==` taking your class as arguments.

```
inline bool operator == (const NameContainer &first,const NameContainer &second){
        return (strcmp(first.name,second.name)==0);
    }
```

and then call `std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), myObjectPredicate))`
with myObjectPredicate being your NameContainer class object with name to be searched in vector.

so here is working solution. you might improve it in details:

```
struct NameContainer{
char name [32];
};

inline bool operator== (const NameContainer &first,const NameContainer &second){
        return (strcmp(first.name,second.name)==0);
    }



int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    NameContainer* _storedNames = new NameContainer[1];
    std::vector<NameContainer> vn(_storedNames, _storedNames + 1);

    const char* cc="piotr";
    NameContainer nc;
    memcpy(nc.name,cc,strlen(cc)+1);
    vn.push_back(nc);

    NameContainer myObjectPredicate;
    memcpy(myObjectPredicate.name,cc,strlen(cc)+1);

    int count=std::count(vn.begin(), vn.end(), myObjectPredicate);
    std::cout<<count;

    return 2400;
}
```

output:

> 1

Comment: it has to be either std::count() or std::find()

Comment: Thanks for you help, I didn't think it would be that easy.

Comment: @user2211776 see complete example

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs on std::count, you'll see that it uses operator== for it's comparisons. Therefore, if you want to use std::count, the thing you want to compare MUST have an operator== defined for it. In your case, you could add one to your NameContainer pretty easily.