# regex_match as predicate

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, predicate

I'm trying to use `std::regex_match()` as predicate in `std::count_if()` with `std::vector<string>` elements in class member function. But don't know how can I correctly bypass second parameter (regex value) into the function.

Is there a way to use `std::regex_match()` as predicate (like `std::bind1st()` for example)?

Example:

```
int GetWeight::countWeight( std::regex reg )
{
    std::cout << std::count_if( word.begin(), word.end(), 
                                std::bind1st( std::regex_match(), reg ) );
    return 1;
}
```

`word` is the `vector<std::string>` where I need to count elements matching `std::regex reg` bypassing outside the class.

Comment: if the signatures don't match up exactly, you can't plug it in directly.. though the answer below seems good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example how you can do this using a lambda in the predicate of `std::count_if`:

```
using Word = std::string;
using WordList = std::vector< Word >;

int countWeight( const WordList& list, const std::regex& re )
{
    return std::count_if( list.cbegin(), list.cend(), [&re]( const Word& word )
    {
        std::smatch matches;
        return std::regex_match( word, matches, re );
    });
};
```

Comment: I also [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771434/counting-matches-in-vector-of-structs) the trick that using a functor as expression.

Comment: @Alex_H: Well, using a lambda saves you from writing all that boilerplate code yourself. ;)

Comment: Ofc, but functor can be more portable. Thank you, Azeem.

Comment: @Alex_H: You are very welcome! :) Can you elaborate a bit on this "portability" of functor vs using a lambda? AFAIK, lambda being part of the language are as portable as any other feature of the language is. And, using a lambda may provide better "locality" compared to a functor. It looks more elegant and writing and maintaining of code can be handled at the same place. Comparatively, using a functor is more writing and more effort while code reviews and maintenance. I'd really appreciate your input on this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I mean different C++ standards. As I know lambda was present in C++11. I think you can meet legacy code that you need to support. I absolutely agree with you reasons about using lambda in code. This functionality makes development cleaner and easier.

Comment: Oh, yeah! In case of backward compatibility issues, functor may be a good choice. But, then, it depends on the project. If it needs to be backward compatible then all these issues should be taken care of. BTW, I got your point. Thanks! :)